# Using DIV in HTML5 Compared to New Container Tags

Tags: html, xhtml, containers, standards

I'm fairly new to HTML. With the rise of HTML5's popularity as a standard (at least, from what I've learned and experience the past couple of semesters), I am wondering if it is still considered good practice to use [DIV] instead of new container elements, such as [main], [nav], etc.

I feel far more comfortable using div's as opposed to the new container tags because of their default values and how much like putty they are when it comes to box modeling a page the way I want it.

My main question is this: If a potential employer or well-seasoned programmer were to look at my HTML5 code and saw div's instead of new container tags, would it be considered bad practice/sloppy coding? Or is using div's still entirely acceptable? Apologies if this is a silly question, but I ask because after this semester is over I'm going to start applying for jobs and want to make sure that my practices/standards are conducive to those that will offer me the highest chance of landing a good employment opportunity!

Comment: Using divs instead of the new containers is ok, especially for backwards compatibility with older versions of IE. remember: _If your solution is dirty, but it works, its not that dirty_ ;)

Comment: divs are harder to abuse. If you write `<div class="footer">`  at the end of your document, nobody's going to complain that you're not doing it right. If, on the other hand, you write `<header class="footer">`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default behavior is a poor reason to not use semantic markup. For one thing, almost every site should use a CSS reset mechanism. Bootstrap, et al, do this for you, and they generally apply `border-box` sizing for convenience.

Aside from polyfills for older browsers, fallback markup is an option. Wrap a classed div with an HTML5 element and apply CSS to both.

Semantic markup allows other types of content consumption beyond the standard web page, such as syndication feeds and print document generation. HTML5 elements provide much contextual information in those cases, as well as for visually-impaired users who employ screen readers and other assistive technology.

All that said, I doubt many employers will deduct for element choice. Overall page structure, markup cleanliness, appropriate internal documentation, etc. are probably more important.

Answer (score 1):

DIV tags do not convey meaning like you get with the html5 specific section tags.  The functionality is the same as far as the block element.  Using the new HTML5 tags help self document your code and not need comments to explain what each DIV does.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to get into using the new tags in HTML5 instead of just divs. You should always want to write as semantically as possible. This helps you grow as a coder and move the web forward.

Answer (score 0):

DIV's are always acceptable, but for a better codding semantic and for the searching engines it's a better practice to use the HTML5 tags. Sooner or later you'll use them so better start practicing.
HTML5 tags are a better way to organize code and help searching engines for best results. It's also help for the CSS because surely you'll save classes and will target the tags.
HTML5 is the way...